# how to return a desired value from sql when using executeNonQuery()

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, data-access-layer

I want to update a record in database if  a condition exists .

```
set nocount off;

if exists ( select * from ParentTable where ID=@ParentID )
  update ChildTable set Title=@Title,ParentID=@ParentID where ID=@ID;
else return -2;
```

but it returns -1 if the ParentID doesn't exists .

I'm using ExecuteNonQuery() to run this procedure

Comment: Have you tried using an output variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of `ExecuteNonQuery` is the number of rows affected, *not* a custom return code. While `-1` (the current return value) seems like a suitable replacement in this particular case, to solve the more general case you'll have to use `ExecuteScalar` and use the pattern below:

```
declare @retval int

if exists ( select * from ParentTable where ID=@ParentID )
begin
    update ChildTable set Title=@Title,ParentID=@ParentID where ID=@ID;
    select @retval = @@ROWCOUNT
end
else 
    select @retval = -1

select @retval
```